# Find ignores Second Value on Collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Meteor its ignoring the second value **{'metadata.diaOferta' : { $in: [diaDeHoy] } }**, on the find, if i put first the **{'metadata.diaOferta' : { $in: [diaDeHoy] } }** it ignores the **{'metadata.tipoMenu' : { $in: [searchMenu] } }** value

```
var searchMenu = Session.get("valueMenu")
 var server = TimeSync.serverTime()
 var diaDeHoy = moment(server).locale("es").add(0,'days').format('dddd');
 return Promociones.find({'metadata.tipoMenu' : { $in: [searchMenu] } },{'metadata.diaOferta' : { $in: [diaDeHoy] } });
```

Its there a way to accomplish this find?

**Answer**

Replace the old find with this and work like a charm

```
 return Promociones.find( {$and:[{'metadata.tipoMenu' : { $in: [searchMenu] } },{'metadata.diaOferta' : { $in: [diaDeHoy] } }]});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Promociones.find(
  {'metadata.tipoMenu' : { $in: [searchMenu] } },
  {'metadata.diaOferta' : { $in: [diaDeHoy] } }
)
```

should be

```
Promociones.find(
  {
    'metadata.tipoMenu' : { $in: [searchMenu] } ,
    'metadata.diaOferta' : { $in: [diaDeHoy] }
  }
)
```

See the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) on `collection.find`.

Comment: I fixed with this  return Promociones.find( {$and:[{'metadata.tipoMenu' : { $in: [searchMenu] } },{'metadata.diaOferta' : { $in: [diaDeHoy] } }]});

Comment: The `$and` is not necessary, `{$and: [{x: y}, {a: b}]}` is equivalent to `{x: y, a: b}`.